# SmartGit randomly stopped working: "Couldn't load main class"

Tags: smartgit

SmartGit worked fine for years.  Suddenly won't start at all:

[image: Couldn't load main class]

If I uninstall and reinstall, it's still the same.  If I move or rename the folders in `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\syntevo\SmartGit`, it's still the same.

If I run it as administrator it works.

This is SmartGit 6.5.8 in Windows 7 Pro 64-bit.

[Asked over a week ago in the official support forum](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/smartgit/conversations/topics/4480) (Yahoo Groups? ಠ_ಠ) but no solution there, so trying here.

Comment: Hahahaha when I opened the question I thought my OS had an issue, because of your picture with the error.

Comment: I had a similar issue when I changed the default path of the Temp/TMP paths to the Windows\Temp directory (Windows 10). Only if I changed it back (e.g. to C:\Temp) - started working again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it turned out, the problem was the `TEMP`/`TMP` environment variables pointing to `C:\Windows\Temp` where **the normal user hadn't permission**, but the administrator had. The `smartgit.exe` tried to write a small `.jar` file there which failed and later could not be found.